# AngularUI datepicker set json date

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using [Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in a project.

How to setup a angular js with json date as initial date? My server returns JSON date and using the same in angular scope object.

However it shows the same json notation in the textbox instead of the dd/MM/yyyy (20/08/2015) format which i expect

[image]

Code is

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"  ng-model="model.GrnDate" is-open="openedGRNDatePicker" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close"
                               class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="openDatePicker($event,'openedGRNDatePicker')" class="btn btn-default">
                                <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>
                            </button>
                        </span>
```

JS

```
$scope.model=data;//loaded from server
 //data.GrnDate="/Date(1440009000000)/"
$scope.openDatePicker = function ($event, opened) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope[opened] = true;
};
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};
```

Comment: if u get that millisecond time separated (1440009000000), you can use `new Date(<mills>)`, then put that in `model.GrnDate` in your controller.

Comment: yes, you should format the date

Comment: Send it as ISO formatted string from server. I used Newtonsoft.Json for this. Then format using filter